# ubuntu 14.04 freezing up after login

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

l am new to ubuntu, and l am having problems after login. freezing up if l try to open any programs. I can f2 and get to the terminal. I have a hp 2008 desktop with amd athlon 64 2.7 ghz, sata hdd 160 gb, and 4 gb of ddr2 of ram with nvidia onboard gpu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 2):

When you get to the login prompt, do not login yet, but instead press together `Ctrl+Alt+F1` key combination. This will get you into text-mode Ubuntu, and you can now input your username, your password and once you are logged in you can run these commands:

```
   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get upgrade
```

you will be presented with a list of updates for your system, and you should press Y for yes to start updating. When finished, run this command:

```
   sudo reboot
```

All these commands depend on your Internet connection being up and running. If you don't have a Internet connection, you should run this command before all of the others mentioned above:

```
   sudo pppoeconf
```

and follow the setup to the end so you have a working internet connection in the textmode console. Then you can run the other commands.

After reboot login as usual, and try and see if you can perform normal operations in ubuntu. If  you still get the same issues, press again `Ctrl+Alt+F1` key combination, and run this command:

```
   sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop xfce4
```

Reboot when finished with this one, use **sudo reboot** again and after you see the login screen, choose Xubuntu session or XFCE session and enter your login username and password. You won't experience any more freezes and hungs, and maybe you'll like Xubuntu desktop more than Unity desktop.